# NodeJS Apple Receipts

Tags: node.js, appstore-sandbox

Folks,
  I am using https://github.com/pcrawfor/iap_verifier to verify apple receipts in the API.

The iOS app is simply POSTing the apple receipt with `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`.

What I now need to do, is forward that to Apple for verification.

code:

```
console.log(req.body);
var receipt = req.body.toString('base64');
console.log(receipt);
var client = new IAPVerifier('appleSecret');
        client.verifyReceipt(receipt, true, function(valid, msg, data) {
            if (valid) {

                console.log("Valid receipt",valid,msg,data);
                var responseObject = {
                    valid: valid,
                    msg: msg,
                    data: data
                };
                responses.respond200(responseObject,res);
            } else {

                console.log("Invalid receipt",valid, msg, data);
                var responseObject = {
                    valid: valid,
                    msg: msg,
                    data: data
                };
                responses.respond200(responseObject,res);
            }
        });
```

output:

```
<Buffer 30 82 1a f8 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d 01 07 02 a0 82 1a e9 30 82 1a e5 02 01 01 31 0b 30 09 06 05 2b 0e 03 02 1a 05 00 30 82 0a a9 06 09 2a 86 48 86 f7 0d ...>
 MIIa+AYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIa6TCCGuUCAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIIKqQYJKoZIhvcNAQcBoIIKmgSCCpYxggqSMAoCAQgCAQEEAhYAMAoCARQCAQEEAgwAMAsCAQECAQEEAwIBADALAgELAgEBBAMCAQAwCwIBDgIBAQQDAgFZMAsCAQ8CA
QEEAwIBADALAgEQAgEBBAMCAQAwCwIBGQIBAQQDAgEDMAwCAQoCAQEEBBYCNCswDQI........... lots of chars

Invalid receipt false Data was malformed { status: 21002 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: The official docs say that status 21002 means "The data in the receipt-data property was malformed or missing."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.body` is already a Buffer, so you'd just need to do `var receipt = req.body.toString('base64');`

However, I think the main problem is that you're passing `false` as the second argument to `verifyReceipt()`. The [second argument](https://github.com/pcrawfor/iap_verifier/blob/beb9a2ae01309a6384b6c6f250a6654b26b90e5d/src/iap_verifier.coffee#L88) should be `true` if `receipt` is already a base64-encoded string. So I think what is happening currently is it is double-encoding the data.

Comment: i've updated my question... getting a `Invalid receipt false Data was malformed { status: 21002 }`

Comment: wish i knew the difference between `verifyAutoRenewReceipt` and `verifyReceipt` methods.

Comment: You have to explicitly pass `true` as the second argument to `verifyReceipt()` to tell it `receipt` is already a base64-encoded string. The default for that parameter is `false` and that is *not* what you want with the way you're currently passing in the receipt data.

Comment: if i add the boolean 'true', i get `Invalid receipt false Shared secret does not match { status: 21004, environment: 'Sandbox' }`

Comment: 'appleSecret' is unlikely your shared secret, it is something provided by Apple in the dev portal.

Comment: im not pasting the actual apple secret in here.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with `verifyAutoRenewReceipt`

Working code:

```
        var receipt = req.body.toString('base64');

        //https://github.com/pcrawfor/iap_verifier
        var client = new IAPVerifier('appleSecret');
        client.verifyAutoRenewReceipt(receipt, true, function(valid, msg, data) {
            if (valid) {
                // update status of payment in your system
                console.log("Valid receipt",valid,msg,data);
                var responseObject = {
                    valid: valid,
                    msg: msg,
                    data: data
                };
                responses.respond200(responseObject,res);
            } else {
                console.log("Invalid receipt",valid, msg, data);
                var responseObject = {
                    valid: valid,
                    msg: msg,
                    data: data
                };
                responses.respond200(responseObject,res);
            }
        });
```